# Payment solution that integrates PayPal

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I'm trying to implement monthly recurring payment on our website. We want user to be able to pay by either directly entering their credit card number or by using their PayPal account. I know that PayPal by itself does this but I'm looking for another solution that would integrate PayPal.

I remember finding a service like this one. It had it's own API and allowed the clients to pay using PayPal or a number of other gateways. All I can remember about the site is that it was themed around mice & cheese.

Would anyone know what that service is, or any other similar service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for cheddargetter, I believe (www.cheddargetter.com).

There are also a number of other options like Chargify, Recurly (where I work), Spreedly.. etc.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I'll be sure to check out the ones you mentionned as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Chargify.com it's great for subscription payment management

Comment: Sadly it does not seem to support PayPal.